# How to get mysql char column type from C# Entity Framework Code First Model

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4, key

I have just done the equivalent of Hello World by creating an Entity Framework Code First model (I have written other C# programs but not with Entity Framework). I created a model like this:

```
class Preferences
{
    [Key]
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MainDatabase { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string DefaultSequence { get; set; }
}
```

and then had a little routine to add a record

```
var newPrefs = new Preferences
{
    StationName = "MATT",
    DefaultSequence = "NONE",
    MainDatabase = "NONE"
};
Preferences prefs = foo.Preferences.Add(newPrefs);
```

which then tries to create the database and fails when adding the primary key with the error

```
"BLOB/TEXT column 'StationName' used in key specification without a key length"
```

because it uses the data type "mediumtext" instead of CHAR or VARCHAR and MySQL can't use that type for a key.

Is there a method that is still more-or-less database agnostic that will tell MySQL to use the preferred type for the key column? Or do I just have to give up and make an integer key?

I also tried variations of the design like this but nothing worked.

```
class Preferences
{
    [Key,DataType("CHAR"),StringLength(30)]
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MainDatabase { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string DefaultSequence { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try fluent mapping column type maybe:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Preferences>()
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .HasColumnType("CHAR(30)");
```

I think this is equivilent of `[Column(TypeName = "CHAR(30)")]` but not certain it's the same.

**Edit:** As per Matt's testing, length is seperate and, "char" may be case sensitive(there are a lot of settings in MySQL and other engiens related to case sensitivity in identifiers, and OS can play a part sometimes, so may vary): `[Column(TypeName="char")][MaxLength(30)]`

Comment: I will try it, but would doing something like that be database agnostic? For example, if I switched to MSSQL in the future would it accept CHAR for a column type?

Comment: Success! Although it is case sensitive and the length has to be in a separate attribute `[MaxLength(30)] [Column(TypeName="char")]`

Comment: @Matt char is ANSI standard SQL, it "should" be agnostic if all engines implement the standards consistently(I'm no expert on this though): http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#data_types-char

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you apply a commonly accepted practice in relational database design, which is to have meaningless primary keys. Meaningless to the business domain that is.

```
class Preferences
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MainDatabase { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string DefaultSequence { get; set; }
}
```

Additional benefit: now you're free to change the StationName whenever necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but if I *really* wanted a char column...how would I do that?

Comment: As someone who for awhile tried to use natural keys, I will never do that again.  There are so many little gotchas, and various levels of support in different frameworks, that you find yourself painted into a corner occasionally.

Comment: Right, I understand, but I have some tables that I need to be backwards compatible with.

Comment: I can't answer your question on a technical level because I'm not familiar with MySql. But you could try to generate a model database-first with DbContext and see what type is used.